# Why's ubuntu 12.10 so fast

Tags: boot, boot-time

I switched from windows to Ubuntu. There's a question in my mind regarding to boot up time of windows and Ubuntu (and many other Linux distros like Fedora,Linux Mint etc.). The question is **"How come Linux boot so fast (10 secs) compared to windows which takes 30-40 secs ?"** I would like to know that what are the factors that decide boot up time and what's the speciality of Ubuntu 12.10 that makes it this fast (in booting process).

Comment: Install bootchart and you can see why YOUR system is so quick ;)

Comment: @EliahKagan I've got 5 linux distros tested on the following specs: Intel Core 2 Duo E6320 processor with 3 GB 667 MHz RAM, a 320 GB HDD and a NVIDIA 9500 GT all fitted on MSI MS-7380 motherboard. Linux distros were tested had a fresh copy Windows 7 installed. It doesn't matter to me time how much Ubuntu takes for most of the people. If you don't know the answer don't post void comments and mark things as duplicate. The question was posted after reading the suggestions provided while posting the question.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm not talking about all Linux based OSes in general in the question(Read the title and question), the comment was just to show you that I've got some valid test results regarding boot time. And yes if you or any one thinks this as duplicate you can always point to original post because the one pointed doesnot explain for the latest Ubuntu 12.10. I'd be happy to remove the question if its really asked before.

Comment: This question IMO is still a dupe. The master question linked to near the top of your question answers *why* Ubuntu boots fast. If you want a comparison of why Ubuntu boots fast *in relation to Windows* this is the wrong site. [su] might accept such a question however. If you feel the answers are outdated [add a bounty](http://askubuntu.com/faq#bounty). If you want an answer based on *your individual* specs than this is "not constructive" or "too localized" as we don't tailor to individual users like that. If you have more questions or need more clarification feel free to ask on [meta].